# Set the field as required in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I am using this form below in admin portal to create a new record but somehow required: true is not working. I have using rails 5. Any idea where I could be going wrong?

```
ActiveAdmin.register Workers do
 permit_params :name, :type, versions: []

 form(html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
    f.inputs do
    f.input :name, as: :string
    f.input :type, as: :string
    f.input :versions, as: :select, input_html: { multiple: true, required: true }
    end
    f.actions
 end
end
```

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? Please describe in detail what you expect to have happen vs what actually happens. Please do not use vague language like "not working" -- use specific explanations of behaviors.

Comment: @anothermh what I mean by not working is that I am able to create the record without even making a selection in the versions  field which I don't want. I want a record not to be  created until a selection is made in versions field.

Comment: @anothermh I am trying in active_admin. So not sure how to implement this active record validation in active admin.

Comment: But at its core, ActiveAdmin relies on Rails. If you tell your Rails model to disallow saving without a field set then it will resolve the issue you've described. If you're hoping to rely on HTML trickery to prevent the form from submitting without a field defined without also restricting it in the model, then you're going about it wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right. Your idea worked. Thankyou @anothermh